# rails で日本語化をしているのですが、attributesの日本語化が適用されません

Tags: ruby-on-rails, i18n

現在の出力画面

> 入力内容にエラーがあります
>   emailを入力してください
>   messageを入力してください

このように、他の日本語化には、成功したのですが、attributesの日本語化だけうまくいかず、困っています。何かアドバイスを頂けたら嬉しいです。

ja.yml

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      contact: お問い合わせ
    attributes:
      contact:
        name: 名前
        email: メールアドレス
        message: お問い合わせ内容
```

※contactモデル,データベースともに存在しています。

contacts/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <strong>入力内容にエラーがあります</strong>
    <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.each do |attr, msg| %>
        <li><%= attr %><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

※一部省略

application.rbに `config.i18n.default_locale = :ja` を設定済み

Answer (score 1, accepted):

キーが抜けてますね。以下のように足してみるとよいと思います。

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    models:
      contact: お問い合わせ
    attributes:
      contact:
        name: 名前
        email: メールアドレス
        message: お問い合わせ内容
```

参考
[Rails国際化(I18n) API | Rails ガイド](http://railsguides.jp/i18n.html#active-record%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AB%E3%81%A7%E7%BF%BB%E8%A8%B3%E3%82%92%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%AA%E3%81%86)

### 追記

キーは足りていたということで、`full_messagesメソッド`を使うとよいと思います。

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
  <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
    <strong>入力内容にエラーがあります</strong>
    <ul>
      <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: すいません書き忘れで申し訳ないのですが、キーは存在しています。

Comment: @Aki なるほど。追記しました。

Comment: ありがとうございます！帰宅次第試させて頂きます！

Comment: ありがとうございます！なおりました！

Comment: @Aki よかったです。解決した場合は回答にチェックマークを入れてください。未解決として放置されてしまいます。またチェックを入れると質問者、回答者ともに信頼度が高まります。

Comment: そんな機能があるのですね！勉強になります。